# Can aws lambda function invoked using RSS feeds

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to use Google News to trigger aws lambda function.

Can i do this using google news RSS feeds or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use Google News to trigger AWS Lambda function.

This is not directly possible since there are not any native triggers for Lambda from Google News. As an alternative approach you can use a [Lambda Scheduled Event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) to poll for the Google News Feed and process.